# Definition of linear independence for abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian group and let $\emptyset \neq X \subset A$. We say that $X$ is linearly independent if for  $x_1, \dotsc, x_k \in X$ and integers $n_1, \dotsc, n_k$, the equation $n_1x_1 + \cdots + n_kx_k = 0 \implies n_i = 0$ for all $i$.

If the abelian group $A$ has the operation of regular multiplication (for example, the group $Q^{\star}_+$ of positive rational numbers under multiplication), does the sum in the definition of linear independence turn into multiplication?

I suppose a more general question is this: When dealing particular abelian groups in applications, does the $+$ in the definition of linear independence get replaced with whatever the operation is on the abelian group?

Comment: Yes, if we use multiplicative notation, we write $n_1x_1+\cdots+n_kx_k=0$ as $x_1^{n_1}\cdots x_k^{n_k}=1$.

Comment: @azif00 Thank you. Ugh, getting used to the double meanings of the symbols in algebra is difficult. Thanks again